# UILabel created at didSelectRowAtIndexPath keep repeating at same position

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uilabel, tableview

Hi I have a problem with `UILabel` repeating the same position at `UITableView`.

I have a custom cell and three `UILabels` . I only display first Label at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the other two at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

When I tap the cell I want display two more Labels display but they are repeating at the same position when I scroll the TableView.

Please help me

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"English";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (isSearchOn) 
    {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"English";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
         NSString *cellValue = _searchResult [indexPath.row];
         cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
         [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica LT Std" size:22]];
    }
    else
    {
        ConversationInEnglish *con = _conversationsInfosnew [indexPath.row];
        _englishLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:10];
        _englishLabel.text = con.english;
        [_englishLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica LT Std" size:22]];
        UIButton *starButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        starButton.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0 , 60, 37);
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        [starButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        starButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryView = starButton;
    }
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.expandedCellIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]){
    }
    else 
    {
        ConversationInEnglish *con = _conversationsInfosnew [indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell1 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        _myanmarLabel = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:222];
        _myanmarLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
        _myanmarLabel.text = con.myanmar;
        [_myanmarLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Masterpiece Uni Sans" size:16]];
        [cell1.contentView addSubview:_myanmarLabel];
        _tonebasedLabel = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:333];
        _tonebasedLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
        _tonebasedLabel.text = con.tone_based;
        [_tonebasedLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica LT Std" size:15]];
        [cell1.contentView addSubview:_tonebasedLabel];
        _speaker = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _speaker.frame = CGRectMake(100 , 80 , 150, 37);
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"speaker.png"];
        [_speaker setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _speaker.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell1.contentView addSubview:_speaker];
        self.expandedCellIndexPath = indexPath;
        self.expandedCellHeight = 110.0f;
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: first of all there is no click in iPhone application, there is always tap and secondly the question is not properly asked, I mean what exactly you want in there want to show label only in one row and that is repeatedly shown to other rows. Or they are displayed in a cell at same place (three of them are staked on each other). I am not getting the question clearly

Comment: ok tap, first i only display one UILabel on TableViewCell and when I tap the cell. I want to display two more Labels. The problem is those two Labels are repeating at Other cell when I scroll.

Comment: This is because you uses the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` this is happend :)

Comment: @Wolvorin I want to display the two more UILabels at didSelectRowAtIndexPath. But the problem is those two UILabels are repeating at same position when I scroll

Comment: @Wolvorin what should I use instead of dequeueResableCellWithIdentifier?

Comment: Look you don't have to replace it but have to modified it. you have to put condition like that it shows the label only in one row for which you want it to show. And for other rows remove those labels from cell using the tag property.

Comment: you need to set the flag for each row not just once so you can able to add the labels for only those rows for which the flag is set not for all rows :).

Comment: if you don't get it or need some more explanation just ask for it :)

Comment: hi @Wolvorin I'm new and appreciate if you could help me with sameple code.thanks. I need more explanation :)

Comment: oh k :) for sample code I need some time :) and what you need is just add one array which contains the row numbers which you tapped or selected and use that number in if condition to compare with the current indexPath.row if both are same then show labels and yeh you have to add those number in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: And still you don't get it have to wait for some time may it will take tomorrow or on monday. Asap I will get time, I crate one demo and post it as answer here ok :)

Comment: thanks @Wolvorin I will be looking forward to seeing your code :)

Comment: Sure I will also try to provide you it asap But till then try to solve it by the above mentioned method :)

Comment: hi @Wolvorin any update? I have tried according to your suggestion but get stuck here :) please help

Comment: Oh sorry for the these much delay It's one project work of mine keeps me busy for these days but don't worry will give you update in few hours just give me some hours. Sorry once again :)

Answer (score 0):

The code where the UILabels are created do not appear to be in the snippet you provided, so I cannot be sure this is your problem, but check that the origin points of your UILabel frames are not too close together. One of the origin points may need to have its x value increased to separate the two views.

Comment: _myanmarLabel = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:222];
This is where you get the UILabel, but not where it was created. You cannot see if there was a frame value set. I would investigate the frame property on both uilabels

Answer (score 0):

try putting yourtextfield.hidden = yes in cell for row at indexpath so each time scroll the textfield will be hidden and in didselect you can show that .hope this helps

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
         [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica LT Std" size:22]]; place this code outside your if (isSearchOn) 
    block ..

Comment: put the break point into the if block and check how many times that part is executed

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get it done is as follow:

First of all have one mutable array with same size with your data array (let it be like this `@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *searchActive;`).

Then in `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method add the below line:
`[self.searchActive setObject:@"1" atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];` (here I use text data in array you can use any thing even you can create your data array as mutable array with dictionary objects, where each dictionary contains two data one is for display in table and second is to deiced which cell is tapped).

Below this line and in between the `[self.tableView beginUpdates];<#HERE#>
    [self.tableView endUpdates];`

just add one line `[self.tableView reloadData];`

And in the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` add the conditional statement as below:

`if([[self.searchActive objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
<# display additional controls here or do what you want to change for the cell#> 
}`

May this will solve your problem :)

**EDIT**
After declaring property you need to `@synthesize` it in .m file.

And After That just put one statement like `self.activeCell = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:<#YOUR TableView's Data Source Array#>];`(**Here I assume that your tableview data source contains string data**)

This is also necessary to have your `activeCell` array at least that much of count as your tableview's data source array have.

Put the above statement inside `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: [self.searchActive setObject:@"1" atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];

Comment: doesn't work . [self.searchActive setObject:@"1" atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];

Comment: Hi @Wolvorin, i can't use setObject:@"1" atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row]

Comment: @koala-london dose the searchActive is one defined property of type `NSMutableArray` ?

Comment: If it is so then will you please, tell me why you can't use `setObject:` on `NSMutableArray` type of object as I can use it in my project.

Comment: hi @wolvorin  i can use the setObject@"1" now , sorry i was using NSArray.  I follow your instruction but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Ok now what is the problem with it? It is working for me in my project. Please provide some details about what is not working.

Comment: Ok I am now looking to you code and try to find out where the problem is just give me some time :)

Comment: Ok got the issue you have used custom cell and also uses the basic cell's detailLabel this causes the problem of showing labels stacked on each other. So first change this use either cell's default detailLabel or put one another label for it in custom cell.

Comment: Secondly `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"English";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   
    if (isSearchOn) {
       
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"English";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];` here you use the same identifier then why repeatedly use the same code twice?

Comment: And if you intend to use both type of cell then change the cell identifier for one of the cell :) and the repetition will be gone for arbitrary cell or all cell :)

Comment: Ok you have got almost to the end now just put else part for `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and in it just put the alpha of the labels to 0 and done. Something like this `else { _myanmarLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:20];
          [_myanmarLabel setAlpha:0.0];
         _tonebasedLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:40];
        [_tonebasedLabel setAlpha: 0.0];}`

Comment: Oh k tell me what is not working? If I am right the other two labels are shown in all the row right? or something else is not working ?

Comment: Not in any row ?? i mean not even when you tap the row ? Ok get it just put `_myanmarLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:20]; [_myanmarLabel setAlpha:0.0]; _tonebasedLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:40]; [_tonebasedLabel setAlpha: 0.0];` in `if` statement body. This will sure show the other two labels only in rows which is been tapped once :)

Comment: Just to know where does you init and fill your `self.activeCell` array in `viewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear` or any other ?

Comment: i haven't init my activeCell Array. is that the problem? I'm a newbie :). sorry

Comment: sorry from me as in my answer I forget to put the init part. :)

Comment: I have just updated my answer just see it and if there is something that you not able to understand just ask for it :)

Comment: sorry, now my app crashed :(. i init my activeCell NSMutable Array with initWithArray and now crash.

Comment: With which array ? the array which is used to fill your table view or any other ?

Comment: It must work as I also use that type of initialization and it worked for me If possible just put the code in comment so I can see how you init the array if you don't mind :)

Comment: Thanks Wolvorin, I feel bad already since I am taking a lot of your time. appreciated it.

Comment: Oh god your initialization is just not proper as the array you use is not simple array which contains all sting data as objects. So forget about the direct init with array just init it with `initWithCapacity:` and put the count of the `_conversationsInfosnew` array. Then just fill the array's all element with some dummy content, like assign `@""` to all element of array using for loop. or what you can do is as done in your code assign c.english or the NSString english to each component of your activeCell array that's it :)

Comment: And don't feel any bad as all here are for helping to each other. `SO` is for that purpose.

Comment: So did you get the solution? or there is still some issues?

Comment: Still a issue. I will try it again and let you know.

Comment: ok I am looking forward to help you out. And don't hesitate to ask for help and also ask any question even if it seems silly from your point of view :)

Comment: No problem I will try my best to help you out